# Create installer for Mac OS X in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4, dmg

I have created a small application in Xcode. How can i make that application as an installer (.DMG). I am new to this Mac OS x and Xcode environment.

Do i have to use a third party software or are there any methods in Xcode4 itself to create a .dmg.

Comment: a .dmg is not an "installer". It's a mountable disk image that typically includes the app bundle (.app directory) and a symlink to /Applications, and a background graphics that shows up in Finder that tells the user to drag the .app to /Applications. (But it is also possible to just run the .app from the mounted .dmg.)

Comment: You can take look here: https://github.com/create-dmg/create-dmg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using PackageMaker which create.pkg package of your Application, this is useful for user deploying your application across multiple-machines via Apple Remote Desktop

[Apple PackageMaker User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Apple Remote Desktop - Software Distribution](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/softwaredistribution.html)

Comment: Thank a lot. I will be trying the tutorials u proposed. Those seems to be what i have been searching. I'll let you know when i am done.

Comment: So what do you guys do now that PackageMaker doesn't run on the latest macOS anymore?

Comment: @c00000fd official guidance from Apple is migrate to pkgbuild or productbuild https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3561448